# Add quotation marks to multiple pieces of text

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I managed to cut out a string and add quotation marks around it. I want to select multiple strings and by pressing a key have AutoHotkey add quotation marks to each string:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Part of a much larger script I'm working on.

[Text Enclosers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eISXu.png)

```
/*
 ╞═══════════✏ Notes ✏═══════════╡ 
» Enclosers

» *TempText is just whats been selected/copied.

» ** If you have a case where you DONT want TempText to be pasted (like for the date Case), just put  Exit  at the end of it so it Exits the process instead of continuing down and pasting TempText (putting Exit makes it not paste TempText)

; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ Base Script Notes ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ 

» Trigger Inserts ════ Ctrl + Y 
» Refresh Script ════  Ctrl + HOME key 
» Exit Script ════════  Ctrl + Escape key 

 ╞────────✏ Notes End ✏────────╡ 
*/

; ╞═══════════ Auto-Execute ═══════════╡ 
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
#Persistent
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SendMode Input ; Makes Send synonymous with SendInput.
SetBatchLines -1 ; Determines how fast a script will run.
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; Sets the matching behavior of the WinTitle parameter.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Scripts own directory. (, FileSelectFolder) - allows user to select a folder.
Menu, Tray, Icon, wmploc.dll, 99 ; Local White Star tray Icon.

; ╞──────── Auto-Execute End ────────╡ 

; ╞═══════════ MENUS ═══════════╡ 
GroupAdd All

Menu Case, Add 
 Menu Case, Color, D6F1FF

; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ 
Menu Cases Insert, Add
Menu Cases Insert, Color, FFF8C7
Menu Insert, Add
; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ 


Menu Encloser, Add 
Menu Encloser, Color, CCFDFF 
Menu Encloser, Add, ″...″   Quotes, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add, '...'    Apostrophes, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add, `*...*    Asterisks, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add 
Menu Encloser, Add, (...)    Parentheses, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add, `{...}    Curly Brackets, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add, `[…] Square Brackets, CCase 
Menu Encloser, Add 
Menu Insert, Add, Enclosers: , :Encloser 
Menu Insert, Color, D1FFF0 
Menu Case, Add, Inserts: , :Insert 
Menu Case, Add 
Menu Insert, Add 


; ◂❖❖❖❖❖❖❖❖▸ HOTKEY  ◂❖❖❖❖❖❖❖❖▸ 
#If GetKeyState("Ctrl","P") 

*Y::    ; ←←←←←← Trigger Key 
  KeyWait CapsLock,T.2 
  If !ErrorLevel{ 
    KeyWait CapsLock,D T.1 
    If !ErrorLevel { 
     sleep 100
    send ^a 
    sleep 200
    GetText(TempText)
    Menu Case, Show 
                            }
    Else { 
             GetText(TempText)
      Menu Case, Show 
             }
                            }
Return
#If 

; ╞═══════════ SWITCH CASES ═══════════╡ 
CCase: 
  Switch A_ThisMenuItem {

; ╞───────────── Enclosers ─────────────────╡ 
    Case "'...'    Apostrophes":
        TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$")
    TempText := "'" TempText "'"

    Case "`*...*    Asterisks":
      TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$")
      TempText := "*" TempText "*"

    Case "″...″   Quotes":
      TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$") 
      TempText := """" TempText """"

    Case "`{...}    Curly Brackets":
      TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$")    
      TempText := "{" TempText "}"

    Case "(...)    Parentheses":
      TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$")
      TempText := "(" TempText ")"

    Case "`[…] Square Brackets": 
      TempText := RegExReplace(TempText, "\s+$") 
      TempText := "[" TempText "]"
}
; ╞═══════════  This has to be at BOTTOM of ALL the CASE THINGS (Pastes TempText) ═══════════╡ 
 PutText(TempText)
    SetCapsLockState, Off
Return
; ╞────────  BOTTOM of ALL the CASE THINGS End ────────╡ 

; ╞═══════════ Functions ═══════════╡ 
GetText(ByRef MyText = "")
{
   SavedClip := ClipboardAll
   Clipboard =
   Send ^c
   ClipWait 0.5
   If ERRORLEVEL
   {
      Clipboard := SavedClip
      MyText =
      Return
   }
   MyText := Clipboard
   Clipboard := SavedClip
   Return MyText
}
 
PutText(MyText) 
{
   SavedClip := ClipboardAll
   Clipboard =
   Sleep 20
   Clipboard := MyText
   Send ^v
   Sleep 100
   Clipboard := SavedClip
   Return
}

CopyClipboard()
{
    global ClipSaved := ""
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := ""
    Send {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}
    Sleep 150
    ClipWait, 1.5, 1
    if ErrorLevel
    {
        MsgBox, 262208, AutoHotkey, Copy to clipboard failed!
        Clipboard := ClipSaved
        ClipSaved := ""
        Return
    }
}

CopyClipboardCLM()
{
    global ClipSaved
    WinGet, id, ID, A
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
    if (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass|Progman")
        Send {F2}
    Sleep 100
    CopyClipboard()
    if (ClipSaved != "")
        Clipboard := Clipboard
    else
        Exit
}

PasteClipboardCLM()
{
    global ClipSaved
    WinGet, id, ID, A
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
    if (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass|Progman")
        Send {F2}
    Send ^v
    Sleep 100
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
    ClipSaved := ""
    Exit
}
 SetCapsLockState, Off
Send, {capslock up}
; ╞──────── Functions End ────────╡ 

; ╞═══════════ Reload/Exit Routine ═══════════╡ 
RETURN

^Home::           ; Ctrl + [Home]
        Reload 

^Esc::      ; Ctrl + [Esc] 
        ExitApp 
; ╞──────── Reload/Exit Routine End ────────╡
```